# Using the Salesforce PHP API to generate a User Profile Report

Tags: php, report, salesforce, soql

Looking to do a security audit of all user permissions. I think I can use the Salesforce PHPToolkit 11 API to generate the report but new to Salesforce and a little confused on where to start.

In Salesforce Setup Under:

```
Administration Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles -> Profile Names
```

If you click on each user name you can see the permissions set and the actions the user is allowed to perform. Wanted a way to generate an excel report for all users with all the permissions for that user.

Example:

```
User Name | Can view Case | Can edit case | Can delete case | etc...
phill             yes            no               no           x...
```

and so on.

I see that in Salesforce I can run a high level report on the Profile but I need to drill down for each user.

Has anyone every done this type of reporting before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to run the query command with some soql to grab each user and join that user to their perms.

Check out the docs (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)

Comment: This might be the only solution. I have downloaded the Force.com Eclipse plugin, would this be a good route to use? New to Salesforce and SOQL

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse plugin definitely works. It should help you get started. Click the salesforce.schema link in the package explorer. This will give you a SOQL explorer view that allows you to run SOQL queries and check relationships between those objects. You'll need to query the user & profile objects to start with (user has a relationship with profile, so that should be easy to get the standard permissions).